# Google chrome crashes after update on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, crash, updates

Yesterday, I updated google chrome to the latest version visiting chrome://chrome/ on my windows 7.
After that, the program started to crash as soon as I opened it.
I tried to reinstall it manually and to uninstall and install again, but nothing changed.
I scanned my pc with /scannow, no errors were detected.
I scanned it with combofix, avast! antivirus and adwCleaner and nothing was found.
I tried to restore my system using two different restore points created from windows update, but both partially failed.
I also tried to load chrome in temporary mode, and it crashed anyway, but just after few seconds.
What can I do?

Comment: **I tried to restore my system using two different restore points created from windows update, but both partially failed.** how exactly did they fail?

Comment: @DavidPostill When system rebooted, I got an error message, something like "couldn't restore a file", but I saw that something was actually restored (infact, I had to download again some windows' updates that I had already installed few days ago)

Comment: Could you try creating a new Chrome profile? It might be that your current profile got corrupted in the upgrade. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142059?hl=en-GB

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks, I followed the steps indicated in the link: the folder "Default" is re-created when I restart chrome, but the browser crashes anyway

Comment: probably there were files left behind, try Revo Uninstaller and use it to uninstall Chrome, and delete all the registry files associated with Chrome, then restart your system, and reinstall it again.

Comment: @iSR5 thanks, I'm trying that and letting you know

Comment: @iSR5 nothing changed, it still crashes :(

Comment: Can you go to Run and type `msinfo32` and hit Enter, then System Information window will popup, see the left column, expand `Software Environment` and click on `Windows Error Reporting`, on the right column, you'll see the errors that Windows has reported, Click on `File` then choose Export save them as Text, and post it here (you can use post it on `pastebin.com` and share the link here).

Comment: @iSR5 thanks: error log is composed by a bunch of lines like [this one](http://pastebin.com/3XFtmZUh)

Comment: Oh, I see, there is some conflicts in the paging system, but I have to know which process is conflicted with. Please generate a dump file for it, by visiting this [link](http://www.sevenforums.com/crash-lockup-debug-how/34940-generating-memory-dump-crashing-process.html)

Comment: @iSR5 I get an error every time I try to install windows debugger :(

Comment: I'll post two comments, if you the first one didn't help, then do the second one. Firstly, try to remove the profile default folder, by copying this `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data` address and paste it on the explorer. Now delete `Default` folder, and then open chrome. See if this will solve it, if NOT then Go to the next comment.

Comment: See if you can do this then, open the Task Manager, then go to the Processes tab, now leave this window open, and open chrome, when open chrome, you should see a new `chrome.exe` process will be opened on Processes list, right click on it, then choose Create Dump File, and the file will be saved on `%LocalAppData%\Temp` just zip it, and upload it for me.

Comment: @iSR5 thanks again for your help. Deleting the folder didn't work. The generated report has a strange format: .dmp. Windows website tells me that there is no program to open the file. Is it normal?

Comment: @Stubborn, yest it's normal, .dmp is Windows dump files format. You have to compress the file as a ZIP file, using [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org) then you can upload it.

Comment: @iSR5 here is it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kair6jnq85ozdwi/chrome.zip?dl=0